# How to simulate ng-click or trigger something when an <option> is clicked?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this select list and I need to `doSomething()` when user selects an `<option>`, I tried with `ng-click` but it doesn't work.
Is there anyway I can get close to `ng-click` but on an `<option>` tag ?

```
<select ng-model="MedsRefund.cityLabel">
  <option value="{{city.name}}" ng-repeat="city in MedsRefund.cities'">{{city.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-change` to determine that the item has changed and take a specific action

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="jsbin">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <pre>{{MedsRefund | json}}</pre>
    <select ng-model="MedsRefund.cityLabel" ng-change="selectedItem()">
      <option value="{{city.name}}" ng-repeat="city in MedsRefund.cities">
        {{city.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);


var mainController = function ($scope) {
  $scope.MedsRefund = {
    cities :[{name:"aName"},{name:"bName"}],
    cityLabel :""
  };

  $scope.selectedItem = function() {
    alert("selected Item " +  $scope.MedsRefund.cityLabel);
  };
};

app.controller('mainController',mainController);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to user Aaron Saunders I kinda hacked a way into my problem this is my solution:

```
  <!-- CITIES POPOVER -->
    <select ng-class="MedsRefund.cityClicked ? 'used-dropdown' : 'selects-dropdown'"
            ng-change="cityClick(city.name)"
            ng-model="city.name">
      <option value="" ng-hide="!MedsRefund.cityClicked" selected>Ciudad</option>
      <option value="{{city.name}}" class="list cities-list"
              ng-repeat="city in MedsRefund.cities | orderBy: 'name' | unique: 'name'">{{city.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.MedsRefund.cityLabel = "Ciudad";
```